# What is the reg expression for Firestore constraints on document IDs?

Tags: regex, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Firestore has constraints on IDs (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas)

What is the Javascript regex for checking the constraints on the following:

- Must be valid UTF-8 characters
- Must be no longer than 1,500 bytes
- Cannot contain a forward slash (`/`)
- Cannot solely consist of a single period (`.`) or double periods (`..`)
- Cannot match the regular expression `__.*__`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Let's look at these points:

> Must be valid UTF-8 characters

I would assume that this is more an issue of your programing language of choice, at least until you tell us that you have raw octets and want a regular expression to validate that a sequence of raw octets is a valid UTF-8 sequence.

> Must be no longer than 1,500 bytes

This will mean something like `.{1,1500}`

> Cannot contain a forward slash

This will mean something like `[^/]{1,1500}` instead of `.{1,1500}`.

> Cannot solely consist of a single period or double periods.

This means something like `(?!\.\.?)` .

> Cannot match the regular expression `__.*__`

This means something like `(?!__.*__)` . Maybe it should mean that no ID is allowed to *start* with `__` and to end with `__` , but maybe it means that no ID is allowed to *contain* a substring that starts/ends with `__`. My approach plays it safe and rejects anything that contains the substring.

Combining the above we get something like:

```
^(?!\.\.?$)(?!.*__.*__)([^/]{1,1500})$
```

Shortening the maximum length to something sensible like 10, some test cases:

Accept

```
foo
foo.
foo..
```

Reject

```
bar/
12345678901
foo__bar__
.
..
```

[Fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/V10WjO/1)